# Recover master database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I got the followng error

```
2015-05-13 12:04:31.00 Server      Using locked pages for buffer pool.
2015-05-13 12:04:31.10 Server      Using dynamic lock allocation.  Initial allocation of 2500 Lock blocks and 5000 Lock Owner blocks per node.  This is an informational message only.  No user action is required.
2015-05-13 12:04:36.14 Server      Node configuration: node 0: CPU mask: 0x000000000000000f Active CPU mask: 0x000000000000000f. This message provides a description of the NUMA configuration for this computer. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2015-05-13 12:04:36.17 spid7s      Starting up database 'master'.
2015-05-13 12:04:36.30 spid7s      Error: 9003, Severity: 20, State: 9.
2015-05-13 12:04:36.30 spid7s      The log scan number (189:72:1) passed to log scan in database 'master' is not valid. This error may indicate data corruption or that the log file (.ldf) does not match the data file (.mdf). If this error occurred during replication, re-create the publication. Otherwise, restore from backup if the problem results in a failure during startup.
2015-05-13 12:04:36.30 spid7s      Cannot recover the master database. SQL Server is unable to run. Restore master from a full backup, repair it, or rebuild it. For more information about how to rebuild the master database, see SQL Server Books Online.
```

Any idea how toresolve it ? I can't start sql server instance ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you tell us if you did something before this error message appeared it will be easier to help.

If you did an update, you can try folloying this [KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2163980/).
If it's not, you could try, as specified in [this article](http://www.mytechmantra.com/LearnSQLServer/Rebuild_System_Databases_In_SQL_Server_2008.html), to run the following command as an Administrator in the SQL Server Setup location:

```
Setup /QUIET /ACTION=REBUILDDATABASE /INSTANCENAME=InstanceName
/SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=accounts [/SAPWD= StrongPassword][/SQLCOLLATION=CollationName]
```

Comment: @canadacanada Which solution solved your problem?